# PHP Class not echoing properly

Tags: php, class

So im in the process of learning php and classes is giving me trouble here,
this code if im not mistaken should echo out Blue and Dusty but for some reason it is sticking to the default green

```
<?php 

class World {
   public $color = 'green';

   public function __construct($color) 
   {
      $this->$color = $color;
   }
}

$World = new World('blue');
echo $World->color;

echo "<br>";

$World2 = new World('dusty');
echo $World2->color;

?>
```

what am I doing wrong? if need be explain it to me like im 5

Comment: first of all change `$this->$color = $color;` to `$this->color = $color;`

Comment: @zzlalani, and that's the only issue :)

Comment: yeah.. possible the only issue as far as I can see..

Comment: Oh boy... Thanks a lot i looked at it for good 10-15 minutes and saw nothing wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change

```
$this->$color = $color;
```

To the following:

```
$this->color = $color;
```

Answer (score 1):

While accessing the class variable you should not access using **'$'**. Just call it using the variable name with the class instance.

So your code currently is,

```
$this->$color = $color;  //WRONG CODE
```

which should be exactly like the below,

```
$this->color = $color;   //CORRECT ONE
```